# How can I use AWS Lambda to read a csv in S3 and output the record count to HTML?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm very new to AWS and this question could very well be impossible in AWS. I'm looking to create a static webpage with S3 that will show how many records are in a csv file. The csv is some fake data about employee attrition, so every row corresponds to an employee. The csv is already in an S3 bucket, and I have already set up the bucket to show a simple static webpage (see below).

Is it possible to use Lambda or anything else to display this record count on the webpage? Seems simple enough, yet I am struggling.

Below is my current webpage, and ideally I would like the record count to be where the big red "X" is.

[image: Ideal Output]

Here is my lambda function so far:

```py
import json
import os
import boto3
import csv

def lambda_handler(event,  context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['fakeemployee']
        file_key = record['s3']['object']['Employee Attrition Data.xlsx']
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        csvfile = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_key)
```

Here is my test configuration in AWS so far:

```py
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "s3": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": "fakeemployee",
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::fakeemployee"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "Employee Attrition Data.xlsx",
          "size": 242.1,
          "eTag": "3df14b4d8bda007b946b9f176b89c9b5",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any advice?

EDIT: I have tried to create a API HTTP Gateway but have run into a "message not found" error when invoking. I used [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop.html#apigateway-http-api-create.console) tutorial to create the API gateway.

Comment: At which part you are struggling ? There will be some javascript involved, are you familiar with javascript?

Comment: @qkhanhpro I was struggling with creating a lambda function that could do this. It doesn't have to be a lambda function though. I'm just supposed to create a "data driven website" with AWS. I'm somewhat familiar with javascript.

Comment: Let's update your question and website to reflect that. You can show that you already know how to make a http call to an API and print the output. Meanwhie I'll try to help you create Lambda that read line count from S3

Comment: What is your _actual_ requirement? Is this for study, or is it for actual work? Frankly, for this requirement, I would trigger an AWS Lambda function when the CSV is uploaded, and then have Lambda count the lines and generate the static page, rather than counting when the page itself is accessed. However, this might not align with your actual requirements, which is why I am asking.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sure, that is a good suggestion. This is just for school, and the assignment is very free form. I'm just supposed to create a "data driven website". Any tips  on how I would have Lambda generate the html?

Comment: @qkhanhpro I just tried to create an API HTTP Gateway for this and failed. See my update  above.

Comment: can you paste your code here for reference? Its not enough for understanding what's going wrong

Comment: @Himakar added my lambda code

Comment: `Employee Attrition Data.xlsx` this is not a csv file and it will not work with csv python library. Also you are not returning anything from your lambda function. Relationship between your website and the lambda is not explained. Exactly how your website is using the function? You need to provide exact details of your setup.

Comment: @Marcin You're right. I'll convert it to csv. Good catch! I would like the lambda function to update the html in the s3 bucket (thereby filling in the red X in the screenshot), but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: So what is the use for your API HTTP Gateway`?

Comment: @Marcin One of the above commenters suggested I "http call to an API ", so I was trying to do this was an API HHTP Gateway.

Comment: How is it going? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, the use-case is that when ever a new CSV file (I assume the file is few megabytes, not in gigabytes) is uploaded to your bucket, you would like to invoke a lambda function which is going to read the file and show how many records are there. The number of records should be used to update a static HTML file in S3.

The steps to achieve that are:

1. Setup [S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) with `s3:ObjectCreated:*` to trigger your lambda function whenever a CSV file uploaded.
2. The event will trigger your lambda, and the function should use `get_object` boto3 call to get the CSV file. Check the number of records in the file by reading the CSV file.
3. In the same lambda, read in your HTML static file from S3 using `get_object`. Update the file in lambda, and then save the new HTML file modified into your bucket using `put_object`.

For that, the lambda needs permissions to read and write to S3, as well as permissions for being invokable by S3 Events.

Other solutions are possible (e.g. with apigateway, dynamodb, etc), but may not be necessary at this stage of your development.

Comment: I am trying to do just that but I wonder if by saving the updated HTML file with the new data can this be enough to see the new file or do you need step 4 to push/trigger a refresh?